# "Filename must be either an absolute pathname or blocklist" Error during boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm using a FS laptop where Lubuntu, Xubuntu, and Puppy Linux are already installed. I'm using a GRUB boot loader which works as expected with the above.

I thought to give Debian a try, so I installed it in a free partition of the HD. As I didn't want to mess my existing GRUB configuration, I didn't install the GRUB during installation, thinking to do it manually afterwards. However, I can't get it to work. I've added this on my menu.lst:

```
title Debian
uuid 5329c69c-c525-4e0e-8026-3418a0db8fb2
kernel vmlinuz root=/dev/sda6 ro
initrd initrd.img
```

'Debian' shows up, but when I select it I get a "Filename must be either an absolute pathname or blocklist" error.

Could someone give me a clue as to what's wrong with the menu.lst entry? I've made sure the uuid code is right (as is the partition number).

Comment: Doesn't one of the 3 installations, the one that manages `/boot`, have an update-grub that scans all the partitions and creates the correct menu entry?

Comment: I tried that, and it gives an entry similar as my manual one, but omitting the last line `initrd intrd.img` which I found odd. Trying to run it anyway, I get a "kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on 
unknown block(0,0)" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) to the kernel file. An absolute path starts at the root directory and starts with a `/`. If `/boot` is on the root partition, that means

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz
```

If `/boot` is on a separate partition, that means

```
kernel /vmlinuz
```

The same goes for `initrd.img`.

In addition, you may need a `root` statement, to point Grub to the partition where those files are. In Grub legacy, that's something like `root (hd0,5)` for what Linux calls `/dev/sda6` (Grub numbers partitions from 0, Linux numbers partitions from 1). The `uuid` directive plays the same role, if your version of Grub supports it.

In a normal Debian installation, `/boot/vmlinuz` and `/boot/initrd.img` are symbolic links that point to a file called `vmlinuz-VERSION` (resp. `initrd.img-VERSION`), where *VERSION* designates the latest kernel version that's installed. Depending on the configuration, those symbolic may be in the root directory instead (but that doesn't work if `/boot` is in a separate partition). Grub can read symbolic links (as long as they're within the same partition), so you can use them to avoid hard-coding the kernel version number in the bootloader configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question in case anyone else is trying to figure this one out. I discovered my two errors:
a) the path wasn't right - I should've used `kernel /boot/vmlinuz`
b) the kernel & initrd names were not right. The following is now working:

```
title Debian
  uuid 5329c69c-c525-4e0e-8026-3418a0db8fb2
  kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-586 root=/dev/sda6 ro
  initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-586
```